# Is DefaultConfigurationAction still supported in lifray 7.1?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-theme, liferay-7.1

Good day;

Want to know if configuration Action is still supported in Liferay 7.1 and if no is the answer what are the other solutions to create a custom configuration action for a portlet.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This sounds suspiciously like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The way you ask this question, just a "yes" wouldn't really be a good option. I'd propose to rather rephrase the problem like "I have [this 7.0 portlet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with a configuration action, but when porting it to 7.1, I'm running into problems A, B and C". The downvote on this question is an indicator for it being overly short. Last pointer: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is still supported.  You can tell by checking the Github repo directly:

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/portlet/DefaultConfigurationAction.java

Comment: Not working is not the same as not supported.  Could be an issue in your code.  Have you verified that both your bundle and the service are both active?  No unresolved refs or dependencies?